# *Dynamic values* array of fixed length or so

Tags: java

I have wrote a search app that put found values in list but now I must to limit it - not more then 10 results. Well - if I have found Equivalent string I will put it to the first place (insert at 0 position) - all others I must store in any other position. 
Could you help me - what storage to choose - to fit this requirements?

so the sample
search string: aa
data for search in: bb, 1aa, aa, .........2aa,.........cc,............9aa,................

result on N-step (aa, 1aa, ....9aa) and we need to add 13aa
so result must be (aa, 1aa, ..., 13aa) (<-put as last for simplicity)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would use ArrayList and check the size of it either by adding a couple of conditions or if you want something more centralized solution then by overriding the add methods like this:

```
public class LimitedArrayList extends ArrayList<String> {
  @Override
  public boolean add(String e) {
      if (this.size() == 10) {
          // Remove an item or return
      }
      return super.add(e);
      // Or add as first item
      // return add(0, e);
  }
  public void add(int index, String e) {
      if (this.size() == 10) {
          // Remove an item or return
      }
      super.add(index, e);
  }
}
```

and the addAll methods also.

Edit: fixed type parameter

Answer (score 0):

There are many solutions to this.
simple solution is: Store all the entries in a database and retrieve only top 10 rows or entries from the database.

ex: select top 10 * from table_name;